Nested Generics with EF Core
My question: is there a way to use nested generics as discriminators for EF Core table mappings?
I have a repo here: https://github.com/sebastianwhiffen/Generically-Typed-Entities-with-EF-Core that demonstrates the use of generics as a kind of 'discriminator' for a table mapping. But NOT nested generics.
In Program.cs, the product of what I've written produces a concise API:
// gets all clients
repo.Get().OfType<Client>() 
    .ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetDisplayName()));

// gets individuals from the DB
repo.Get().OfType<Client<Individual>>()
    .ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetDisplayName()));

// gets companies
repo.Get().OfType<Client<Company>>()
    .ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetDisplayName()));

// you get the idea
repo.Get().OfType<Client<SoleTrader>>()
    .ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetDisplayName()));

The DbContext looks like this:
public class MyDB : DbContext
{
    public MyDB(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.MapClientTypes();
    }
}

And I can map the client types using reflection (to avoid a lot of manual labour in a real application where there could be heaps of types).
public static class ModelBuilderHelper
{
    public static void MapClientTypes(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var clientTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IClient).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var clientType in clientTypes)
        {
            var genericClientType = typeof(Client<>).MakeGenericType(clientType);
            var entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(genericClientType);
            var dataProperty = genericClientType.GetProperty("Data");
            entityTypeBuilder.OwnsOne(dataProperty.PropertyType, dataProperty.Name);
        }
    }
}

Basically, I want to take it a step further:
repo.Get().OfType<Entity>()
    .ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetIdentifier()));

but I am running into walls whichever way I turn.
This is how I am trying to extend the demo. I am trying to add another layer of generics above the Client<T> type called Entity<T>.
Client looks like this
public class Client<T> : Client where T : Entity, IClient, IEntity, new()
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        Data = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public override string GetIdentifier() => Data.GetIdentifier();
}

public abstract class Client : Entity;

And the entity looks like this:
public class Entity<T> : Entity where T : Entity, IEntity, new()
{
    public T Data {get; set;}

    public Entity()
    {
        Data = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public override string GetIdentifier() => Data.GetIdentifier();
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public abstract string GetIdentifier();
}

The first issue I am running when attempting to expand this to include the ability to query all entities is this error:

The instance of entity type 'Entity' cannot be tracked as the entity type 'Client.Data#SoleTrader' because the two types are not in the same hierarchy.

And that comes from my generic repos _context.Add(entity) call.
I've published the code that's giving that error here: https://github.com/sebastianwhiffen/Complex-Generic-EF-Entities if you want to take a look for more context.
But in summation. I want to be able to create a hierarchy of nested generic objects starting with Entity, and (in theory) be able to continue that nesting for as long as I want downwards
Any Ideas? any other solutions that provide me that concise generic repo syntax while still avoiding major wrists pains from writing out
public class SoleTraderClient : Client<SoleTrader> { }
public class SoleTraderEntity : Entity<SoleTrader> { }
etc...

for every possible combination of entity structure

This looks like a huge mess if I'm honest. You shouldn't be using generics in this way.

@DavidG how would you do it

I agree with DavidG. Even if you could get this to work, chances are that it will be so complex that few, if anyone, would understand how it works. And I would be careful with using reflection to generate entities, there is a significant risk of unintended behaviors. It is also not clear to me what benefit generics give you over regular inheritance & properties.

What's the benefit of nesting types in an unlimited inheritance hierarchy? IMO you should avoid type inheritance as much as possible when mapping classes to database tables, even in one inheritance level. It nearly always causes significant performance and validation problems.

Do you even need generics? Isn't deriving Individual, Company and SoleTrader from Client enough? I don't see the point of having a Client<Company>. If you have a class Company : Client then Company is a Client and inherits everything Client has.

From the original example that they put up in GitHub, the important take-away is the word "unorthodox". The author of that library was faced with a legacy data structure in a company. Those initial design choices form a MASSIVE technical debt that generated a lot of interest in terms of complexities to work on that code base, and will continue to incur future interest as they have to find "clever" ways to try and abstract it into something remotely work-able. By putting their example up, it's to help other poor souls facing similar situations. Not creating NEW debts.

@StevePy I put the original example up on github.
However, I can read the room. Clearly, this is a whacky way of doing things. I'm just experimenting so please don't take what I've written as gospel. Only bored and prodding around. I'm going to make this work in my own time. but good to know that this isn't advisable.
At the end of the day I am looking for a way to concisely query a set (Entity), and then aggregate subsets (clients) and then again (company clients) etc ect through a single generic repo.
repo.Get().OfType()

@OlivierJacot-Descombes in this minimal example it's alright, but the idea is to not be restricted when I decide to add more entity types.
yes I could do class Company : Client.
but in the future when I add "class Partner" I cant do "class Company : Client, Partner". because c# doesn't support multiple inheritance.
